# Use URL from database and save actual image to AWS S3

Tags: c#, vb.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use the url's in my database and download the images to AWS s3.
I am scratching my head because I am not sure how to do this.

I am trying to do this via a windows service

I have attempted the following:

```
Sub Images()
        Dim ds_data As DataSet
        Try
            ds_data = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Item("ConnectionString"), CommandType.StoredProcedure, "ETSP_GET_PHOTO_URLS")

            For Each dr As DataRow In ds_data.Tables(0).Rows
                Dim ImageURL = dr("column_URL")

                Dim Client As New WebClient
                Client.DownloadFile("ImageURL", "FileName")
                Client.Dispose()
                s3.UploadFile("me", "Test", "ImageURL", True, "me.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com", "Ireland", 0)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

ETSP_GET_PHOTO_URLS brings back a url : `http://img.website.net/p/1483/278227_20094171232290.jpg`

The `s3.UploadFile` expects values as follows: `BucketName, FolderName, FileName, makePublic, UploadDirectory, region, cacheTime`

I am very new to this. Any help would be appreciated. I dont mind C# or VB help.